# Measure of a Cartesian Product of a Null Set and Another Euclidean Space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, $n\geq 2$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, and $k<n$. Let $N\subset\mathbb{R}^k$ be a $k$-dimensional Borel null set. Consider the Cartesian product $N\times\mathbb{R}^{n-k}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.

My intuition suggests that $N\times\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ must be a null set as well (using the $n$-dimensional Borel measure, that is), but I cannot seem to prove it. The problem is that the usual strategy of approximating only $N$ by ever smaller rectangles from the outside does not work, since $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ has infinite measure (using the $n-k$-dimensional Borel measure), so that a more sophisticated limit argument must be used, in which $N$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ are jointly approximated by small rectangles (of the appropriate dimension) to be picked “strategically.”

I would appreciate any ideas or hints.

Comment: Do you know about Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @studiosus Thanks for the hint. I thought about using Fubini. However, I needed this result in order to formally _prove_ that the product measure generated by the two product measures, $m_k$ and $m_{n-k}$, is actually identical to the $n$-fold product measure $m_n$. Using Fubini would have been cheating, because I would have implicitly used a result based on the one to be proved.

Answer (score 6):

Never mind. Since the Borel measure is $\sigma$-finite, one can write $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j$ such that $m_{n-k}(E_j)<\infty$, where $m_{n-k}$ is the appropriate Borel measure. Now,

\begin{align*}
m_n(N\times\mathbb{R}^{n-k})=m_n\left(N\times\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j\right)\right)=m_n\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}N\times E_j\right)\leq\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}m_n(N\times E_j).
\end{align*}

Now one can use the approximation argument I mentioned above to prove that $m_n(N\times E_j)=0$, since $m_{n-k}(E_j)<\infty$ for any $j\in\mathbb{Z}_+$.